# IndexedDB read completing before write finishes

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

I am streaming a logfile and when a certain log entry is captured (let's call these Event A) I write them to IndexedDB. When another certain log entry is captured (say, Event B) I search the object store for a matching Event A entry.

This works fine as long as Event A and Event B don't happen consecutively.  If they happen consecutively (let's say Event A is written to the logfile and then Event B is written immediately afterwards) then the entries from Event A are not found.

I tried to read Event A in "readwrite" mode but that didn't work - which was unexpected as I thought opening in readwrite would mean it wouldn't try and run the transaction until Event A had completed.

One solution I am thinking of implementing is to track each transaction and only initiate a search if all transactions are complete - but it seems like a lot of effort for something I imagine is fairly common?

```
addEntry(store: string, entry: any): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.dbPromise.then(db => {
            let transaction = db.transaction(store, "readwrite");

            transaction.oncomplete = (evt: any) => {
                resolve(true);
            }

            transaction.onerror = (err: any) => {
                this.logger.error({
                    originalError: err,
                    message: 'transaction error',
                    data: {
                        store,
                        entry
                    }
                });
                reject(err);
            }

            transaction.onabort = (evt: any) => {
                this.logger.error({
                    originalError: evt,
                    message: 'transaction aborted',
                    data: {
                        store,
                        entry
                    }
                })
                reject(evt);
            }

            let objectStore = transaction.objectStore(store);

            let request = objectStore.add(entry);

            request.onerror = (err) => {
                console.dir(err);
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            this.logger.error({
                originalError: err,
                message: 'journalDBService.addEntry error',
                data: {
                    store,
                    entry
                }
            });
        })
    })
}

getEntry(store: string, key:any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.dbPromise.then(db=>{
            let transaction = db.transaction(store, "readonly");
            let objectStore = transaction.objectStore(store);
            let request = objectStore.get(key)

            request.onsuccess = (evt) => {
                resolve((<IDBRequest>evt.target).result);
            }

            request.onerror = (err) => {
                this.logger.error({
                    originalError: err,
                    message: 'journalDBService.getEntry request error',
                    data: {
                        store,
                        key
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            let report = {
                originalError: err,
                message: 'journalDBService.addEntry error',
                data: {
                    store,
                    key
                }
            };
        })
    })
}
```

EDIT: The actual offending code below

```
this.journalDB.getEntry(journal.JournalEvents.missionAccepted, (<journal.MissionAccepted>data).MissionID).then(result => {
if (!result) {
    this.journalDB.addEntry(journal.JournalEvents.missionAccepted, data)
        .catch(err => {
            let report = {
                originalError: err,
                message: 'journalService.handleEvent error',
                data
            }
            this.logger.error(report);
        })
}
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexed DB requires that "readonly" transaction scheduled following a "readwrite" transaction with overlapping scope would not run until the "readwrite" transaction is complete and thus would see the results of the writes. So yes, your expectation is correct.

So... the possibilities are:

- You're dealing with a buggy implementation (which browser? can you reproduce this stand-alone?)
- The transactions are not starting in the order you expect; are you able to log the `db.transaction` calls and verify the order? (i.e. maybe the `dbPromise.then` handlers aren't running in the order you expect)
- There is some other logic error, e.g. the key is incorrect so the value is not seen

Can you narrow down which one of these it is?

Comment: Was option 2 in this case.  It was nothing to do with my addEntry function and everything to do with the fact that the 2nd read function was scheduled before the 1st read function resolved and scheduled its readwrite transaction.